# Semantic UI Search Module does not display json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, semantic-ui

I am trying to get Semantic UI's Search autocomplete to work. Everything seems to be working, except for the fact that the autocomplete always says no results found.

This is an example search:

[image]

This is the case even though the server response seems to work fine.

Here is the server responding with JSON:

[image]

Finally, here is my JQuery code:

```
$(".ui.search").search({
    apiSettings: {
        url : "/subtopics/search.json?query={query}"
    },
    fields: {
        results : 'subtopics',
        title : 'name'
    },
    minCharacters : 2
})
;
```

From all the examples I've seen this is the proper way to tell Semantic UI what fields to look at, but it's not working.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to add these headers into JSON response. 
( php example )
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); header('Content-type: application/json'); Maybe Content-type: application/json could make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out using the onResponse callback included in the Semantic UI documentation (http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#response-callbacks) is the solution to this problem.

Here is the code that ended up working:

```
$(".ui.search").search({
    type: 'category',
    minCharacters: 3,
    apiSettings: {
        onResponse: function(serverResponse) {
            var
                response = {
                    results: {}
                }
            ;
            //translate Server API response to work with search
            $.each(serverResponse.subtopics, function(index, subtopic) {
                var
                    topic = subtopic.topic || 'Unknown',
                    maxResults = 8
                ;
                if(response.results[topic] === undefined) {
                    response.results[topic] = {
                        name: topic,
                        results: []
                    };
                }
                //add result to category
                response.results[topic].results.push({
                    title: subtopic.name
                });
            });
            return response;
        },
        url: "/subtopics/search.json?query={query}"
    }
})
;
```